# Retrieving records from MySQL in specific order

Tags: mysql, fetch, sql-like

I want to search in my db and I generate a query like this:

```
$optionArray = explode(' ', $searchExpression);  

$query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_object WHERE tag LIKE "%'.$optionArray[0].'%" OR 
           tag LIKE "%'.$optionArray[1].'%" OR  tag LIKE "%'.$optionArray[2].'%" 
             OR ...';

executeQuery($query);//Function to execute above query, no matter which function
```

Now here is my question:
Is there any way to return records according to number of conditions that are satisfied?
For example I want an object which satisfy more `LIKE` condition to retrieve in higher priority.

Am I clear? If I didn't describe my problem clearly please notice me.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

---

EDIT:
When I execute below query into MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_object` 
WHERE tag LIKE '%water%' OR tag LIKE '%melon%' 
ORDER BY (tag LIKE '%water%' + tag LIKE '%melon%') DESC
```

MySQL reply me this error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ tag LIKE '%melon%') DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can.

```
'ORDER BY ((tag LIKE "%'.$optionArray[0].'%") + 
           (tag LIKE "%'.$optionArray[1].'%") + 
           (tag LIKE "%'.$optionArray[2].'%")) DESC'
```

What it does is it sums up the value return by the `LIKE` clause. Eg

```
assume that the value of TAG is Hello.
```

so

```
tag LIKE '%ell%'      ==> 1
tag LIKE '%shell%'    ==> 0
tag LIKE '%hellos%'   ==> 1
tag LIKE '%x%'        ==> 0
                      -------
                          2  => this value will sorted out.
```

Comment: Thanks great John, such a nice solution. I appreciate your knowledge grace

Comment: Could you see my post changes please, I got an error while applying your solution. thanks

Comment: wrap the `LIKE` with parenthesis, `(tag LIKE '%water%')` eg. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bd66a/1

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a neat feature of treating booleans as 1s (for "true" results) or 0s (for "false") results.
One way to use this is to sum the number of conditions the row is fulfilling, and order according to that (php string-building removed for clarity):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (SELECT *, 
          tag LIKE '%option1%' +
          tag LIKE '%option2%' + 
          ... +
          tag LIKE '%optionN%' AS num_matches) t
WHERE    num_matches > 0
ORDER BY num_matches
```

Comment: Thanks dear, nice solution, I appreciate your answer